# Static variable never get updated

Tags: java

I am trying to assign a new value to the `ans` variable  but it never gets updated. I run many input (x, n) but showing result x final answer. Can someone explain?

```
public class Solution {

    static int ans = 1;
    public static int power(int x, int n) {

        if(n==0)
            return 1;
        if(n==1)
            return x;

        ans = ans * power(x,n-1);
 
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your Unit tests

Comment: Why do you even want a static variable, here? Just use a local variable...

Answer (score 3):

A static variable is associated to the class itself. In case of more instances of that class, a static variable is common to all instances. However, during recursion, for each function call a new stack frame is pushed onto the stack memory with all the variables inside that method.

In your case the variable `ans` will be copied to the stack for each recursive function call creating multiple copies (yes even if static). So if `ans` is modified in the stack by a recursive call, the value of `ans` in the (parent) calling function is not affected.

For `power(2,3)` this is what happens:

```
power(2,3) ans=1
        power(2,2) ans=1
                power(2,1) ans=1 -> returns 2
        ans * 2 -> returns 2 because ans is still 1
ans * 2 -> returns 2 because ans is still 1
```

This is a simplified version of your function without using the extra variable:

```
public static int power(int x, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n == 1)
        return x;
    return x * power(x, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: I know the correction but I want to know why static variable does not update.

Comment: ans = ans * power(x,n-1); why new value does not assign to ans

Comment: Hi @Pulkit I updated my answer. I think this is an interesting question that shows the difference between heap and stack memory. I hope the answer is clear enough now.

Comment: thanks @Marc for reply. But you said if i made some change in stack frame it doesn't show in class variable But when i made some changes like  `ans = ++ans * power(x,n-1)` ans variable value get updated. why?

Comment: That is the same as `ans++;ans = ans * power(x, n - 1);`. `ans` gets updated before calling the function recursively, so the updated value is copied to the stack. Please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: _"So if ans is modified in the stack, the value is not reflected in the class variable."_ That makes no sense: if `ans` is modified, it is by definition reflected in that class variable, because that is what is modified. I guess you mean something else, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: "A static variable is common to all instances of a class" - I generally regard this as a misleading way of explaining static. It somewhat implies that there has to *be* an instance of the class at all. Instead, I prefer to explain it as "a static variable is associated with the class itself, rather than being specific to individual instances of the class".

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks I updated my answer with your feedback.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, I updated my answer with your feedback

Answer (score 1):

1. Your static variable is not the problem.

The code should be:

```
ans = x * power(x, n-1);
```